# Error Connecting to a VM on a different domain

Tags: c#, wmi

This code works fine when opening two other VMs but gives me an RPC error on 
opening a computer on a different domain. At the moment I am using the ConnectionOptions class to connect to the remote computer

```
`options.Username = dif_users[i];  // Assume correct user name
        options.Password = dif_passwords[i]; // Assume correct password
        if (i == 2) // To execute for the third VM. (i = 0 in the beginning)
        {
            //
            options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
            options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DIFFERENT_DOMAIN";


        }
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + comps + "\\root\\cimv2", options);

        scope.Connect();  // RPC server is unavaialaible
```

`

Comment: Do you use ldap or kerberos as authentication provider in the active directory for the third VM?
Does the connection work to other VMs?

Comment: kerberos is used as an authentication provider in the active directory. The connection to the other two VMs work (I think its because my computer and the other two computers are on the same domain while the third uses another one)

Comment: Specify "kerberos" instead of ntlmdomain in your Authority string